# Microsft Graph: Unable to expand ListItem for a drive item when using Delta Query

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

To access the customized columns in SharePoint site-document library, via delta query. I tired the below API and I am getting error - bad arguments [when using expand to get the listItem].

GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/root/delta?expand=listItem

But according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), delta query should support the Optional query parameter.

Is there any mistake in the above approach or other way to get the listItem in delta query?

Comment: Use `items` rather than `listItems`. Use this query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drive/root/delta?expand=items`

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: Thanks for your response, Shiva Keshav Varma. I tried, but the response is same as the one that I get without expand query.

Comment: Maybe same as this issue: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/8321

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `$select` clause instead of `$expand`?

```
GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/root/delta?$select=listItem
```

It should include changes to `listItem`

Comment: Hi,  I have tried this also, but no list items in the API output.

Comment: Sounds like a [bug or wrong documentation to me](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/8321), as @user2250152 updated above..!!